# Question about convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The sequence $a_n = \dfrac{n^2-1}{n^2+n+1}$ is said to converge to 1 . When we divide the numerator with the denominator we get $$a_n = 1-\dfrac{(n+2)}{n^2+n+1}$$. The text I am referring to says, we only need to show that, $$r_n = \dfrac{n+2}{n^2+n+1}$$ converges to 0 as n tends to infinity and proceeds to say that $$\forall n>2, n+2<2n$$ and that $$n^2+n+1>n^2$$. I get the proof till this point, then the author states $$0<r_n<2n/n^2=2/n$$ for n>2, and says this determines the largest estimate of how much the sequence $a_n$ differs from 1. What did the author do here? why and how did they bound $r_n$? How does this (how does bounding $r_n$ ..?) prove that the limit of $a_n$is infact 1

Comment: I think the author intended to define $r_n$ as $\frac{n + 2}{n^2 + n + 1}$, and then show it tends to $0$, not $1$. The squeeze argument in the final line shows $r_n \to 0$.

Comment: Oh typo, Let me edit it

Comment: By tend to 1 , i meant $a_n$ tends to 1 sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I'll make it more clear

Comment: All done , my bad ^⁠_⁠^

Comment: You still haven't fixed the main mistake: it must be that you need to show that $\;\lim r_n=0\;$ , not $\;\lim r_n=1\;$ ...!

Comment: My bad , i beg your pardon, now it's fixed

Comment: A more elegant approach is to divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$. Then almost all summands tend to $0$ except the $1$ in the numerator and the $1$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Peter , Ah thats a really nice way to do it , it simpler and more efficient and also makes the proof shorter but what exactly is the author trying to doo!?

Comment: I have deleted my comment now the question has been fixed. The point is that if $a,b,c$ are all positive with $b\gt c$ then $\frac ab \lt \frac ac$

Comment: Yes , i get it now , i just suddenly couldn't think what the author did there as , to me that came out of nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe and be sure you understand and can prove the following inequalities:

$$0\le r_n=\frac{n+2}{n^2+n+1}\le \frac{n+n}{n^2}=\frac 2n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

...and now apply the squeeze theorem.